# Can't connect Amazon rds database in Amazon ec2?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a console application that has Amazon rds connection with Entity Framework . It is running well in my local PC. But When I am running my application in Amazon EC2 It can not connect to my Amazon RDS database and saying 'The underlying provider failed on open' . My connection string of entity framework is ...

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/YhFinModel.csdl|res://*/YhFinModel.ssdl|res://*/YhFinModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=datasourcename,portnumber;initial catalog=databasename;persist security info=True;user id=userid;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you looked at your security groups? I think you will need to add the EC2 security group you are using to have port access to your RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added security group in ec2 already but nothing works . I also created another ec2 in another region and try to run that console application but does not work.

Comment: Apologies as my first response sounded confusing. In the management console for RDS, did you add the EC2 security group here?
https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-east-1#security:

Comment: Please can you be more specific. I have added db security group in RDS instance .

Comment: Go to the RDS console. Select 'DB Security Groups'. There is a default group already created, or maybe a custom you have already added. Whichever group your RDS instance is using look in the Description tab below after selecting one. There is Connection Type column. Choose the drop down that has CIDR/IP and select 'EC2 Security Group'. It should then give you another drop down of the EC2 Security Groups you have configured in your account. Make sure to select and Add the group that your actual running EC2 instance is using.

Comment: This worked for me.  Note that you need to reboot the RDS instance after adding the EC2 security group before it will work!

Answer (score 3):

If you have your EC2 instance and RDS instance in different regions you will have to go to RDS Security Group and enter the *external* IP of the EC2 instance as CIDR/IP. At least that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly newer version that was required to get this to work.  Click RDS Dashboard. Select your RDS Instance->Click on Details Icon->Click on Security Groups URL that is attached the selected RDS instance. This will place you into Security Group Settings of EC2. Once you select your Security Group, click on Inbound tab. Here you need to possible modify or Create a new rule (MS SQL, TCP, Port (eg 1433), and then an IP Address/IP Address Range of allowable requests. You could set all IP Addresses to confirm it works, and then tighten up the security to IP Address range based on instances, and/or testing environment IP Address.

good luck.